# How can I get a random image from image search using a command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I know I can make a command like:

```
    async def cat(self, ctx):
      response = requests.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
      data = response.json()
      embed = discord.Embed(
          title = 'Kitty Cat ',
          description = 'Cat',
          colour = discord.Colour.purple()
          )
      embed.set_image(url=data['file'])            
      embed.set_footer(text="")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

*not my code btw*
But how do I make a command to search like !image computer and it gets a random computer image from image search and sends it to the channel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Very rarely do people just simply write code for you. We'd like to see you put some effort into your code and display it in the question. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to see how.

Comment: You either need to use a google api, such as [Google-Images-Search 1.3.8](https://pypi.org/project/Google-Images-Search/), or find an api like [Unsplash Source](https://source.unsplash.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[Unsplash Source](https://source.unsplash.com/)** API, as suggested by [Bagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14420546/bagle).

```
@command(name = "img")
    async def cat(self, ctx, arg):
      embed = discord.Embed(
          title = 'Random Image ',
          description = 'Random',
          colour = discord.Colour.purple()
          )
      embed.set_image(url='https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?{}'.format(arg))            
      embed.set_footer(text="")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And execute the command with

```
{bot_prefix}img computers
```